# Google doesn't seem to update the description or title of my homepage

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, sitemap, meta-description

Before we launched our website, we had set up a "coming soon" page and google picked up the title and description from its contents. So the description in the search results said:

> Coming soon! Visit example.org for updates.

It's been a few weeks since we launched our website. We've even created a sitemap and submitted it to Google. In Google Search Console, the pages have been crawled and all the pages are appearing as expected on Google, EXCEPT the homepage which is still not updated! The title and description of the homepage in google search results still says "coming soon.".***

I checked on bing too, but it appears to be fine there.

All other pages seem to be indexed fine on Google. I don't even have any crawl errors in my reports. So what seems to be the problem? I've already waited for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4):

Being a new site, and home page, Google is going to crawl and update its index of your content less frequently then established sites that have higher PR, dynamic content, etc. But they will update it sonner rather then later. Just keep seeking incoming links and try to get some changing/dynamic content on the home page.

Comment: I guess I'll have to just wait it out then. I just resubmitted the sitemap for the third time. The deal is that it's being able to catch updates, changes, additions to other pages... but unfortunately not the homepage.

Answer (score 3):

Sign up for a [Google Webmaster](http://www.google.com/webmasters) account. You can submit a sitemap which will help Google crawl your site. I've noticed that sites that I have in my webmasters account get crawled more frequently and you can request a crawl.

Comment: I have signed up for one. Submitted the sitemap, resubmitted it and have no crawl errors either. No luck!

Comment: How long are you giving Google? I've had some sites take a week before Google has accepted my sitemap.

Comment: looks like google indexed it now perfectly. Took more than 2 weeks. Problem solved, phew! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can manually request indexing the new version with google search console.

1. Login to Search Console
2. Choose your property
3. Navigate to "Crawl"
4. Navigate to "Fetch as Google!
5. Click "Fetch"
6. Wait until the request appears in the table (a few seconds)
7. Click "Request indexing"

This will tell google to have a look at this page and index the new version.

[image: Manually index with google search console]

Answer (score 0):

Google is unable to find a new site upto some weeks sometime to Some months. even if you submitted a sitemap. 
Your Screenshots links are not there so I cant find that how much pages are live on your site.
 if you submitted your empty sitemap to Google then it can't index your site homepage sometime and takes more time.

But for a new site, you have needed to increase the indexing speed of your site by using some proven [strategies](https://neilpatel.com/blog/google-index/) to index website in Google ASAP.

Use every trusted platform to increase the indexing rate. Make sure Google will found your site on some big sites.