# Why google isn't updating my site title in search results?

Tags: search-engines, google-search, robots.txt, googlebot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google doesn't seem to update the description or title of my homepage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8710/google-doesnt-seem-to-update-the-description-or-title-of-my-homepage)

I had my domain for few days before I uploaded site to it, and it had one title, and then when I uploaded content it should get new title, but with my misunderstanding of WordPress it had blocked robots.txt and keyword with **no-index** and **no-follow**.

But I removed that like 7 days ago, and I see in reports that Google bot is crawling over my site, but my site title isn't updating, it still has old domain title when site wasn't there...

My robots.txt has now:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

I have clear title tag on every page.

How long does it take to update? Do I need to check something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the time you see Googlebot hit your site in your server access logs, to the time it's updated the index, and the time it has updated their cache the dates will vary. It depends where they are in the cycle of pushing out an update to index and cache servers. Sometimes it can be within minutes other times it can take a ~week

This is something you just have to wait and be patient for.