# How can I get Google to update my sites description?

Tags: seo, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google doesn't seem to update the description or title of my homepage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8710/google-doesnt-seem-to-update-the-description-or-title-of-my-homepage)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The site description shown is very old, from way back in January of this year. Yet the image shown is current.

How can I ask Google to update my sites description?

Answer (score 2):

The snippet text you are referring to can come from the following places:

Can come from many different places depending on the situation

- **If the crawler can access the URL**

  - Meta Description Tag

    - `<head>...<meta name="Description" content="Your Description" />...</head>`
  - Pull the description from within the page

    - Tries to pull the most relevant part of the page.

---

- **If the crawler can't access the URL**
  (robots.txt, site was down, etc...)

  - Relies on the [Open Directory Project](http://www.dmoz.org/) to retrieve text.

---

## Webmaster Tools Account and Sitemap Setup

Setting up a [Webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) account and [Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78808&topic=2371325&ctx=topic) would do alot to fix this.

---

## Change the Crawl Rate

Also try to increase the frequency with which Google crawls your page using `Webmaster Tools->Settings->Crawl Rate` (but not so much that it [overwhelms the bandwidth of your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48620&topic=2371325&ctx=topic))

You can also find out when the last time Google has crawled your site was by visiting the cached version of the page in the search results.

*(Note however that you can't change the crawl rate of a subdirectory of your site, you can only change it from the root url of the site).*

---

## Reduce redundant crawling of pages

#### Set at Canonical URL/Domain

Setting a [Canonical Domain](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231&topic=2371325&ctx=topic) for your site can reduce reduce redundant visits from the Google crawler.

Setting a [preferred URL (a Canonical URL)](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066) for pages can reduce redundant visits to the [same information that can be reached by various URLs](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394).

#### Parameters

Also, if your site has alot of non-standard parameters for changing what sort of content is displayed a page, it's possible that Google is running out of resources for crawling your site, so you should [configure your URL parameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1235687&topic=2371325&ctx=topic).

---

Comment: According to the cache version, the last time Google crawled it was in April 4. Can I ask Google to update it's information? I can't find a link to do that anywhere.

Comment: You can't force the Google Crawler to crawl the page, but you can change certain settings of your Webmaster Tools account to increase the likelihood that it will be re-crawled sooner.