# Why isn't google updating my description of my website?

Tags: web-development, godaddy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google doesn't seem to update the description or title of my homepage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8710/google-doesnt-seem-to-update-the-description-or-title-of-my-homepage)

I had created a website,hosted it on [godaddy.com](http://godaddy.com).

I edited it recently .(fetched and uploaded files using FileZilla)
I put a description on each page using meta tags.
It has been more than 3 days since I did that.

When I google for my website name , the first result that shows is my website name.

But the description under it still hasn't been updated.

Why not?

Comment: I believe it will take a little longer, the last time I updated the title and description of my website it took google 3-4 weeks to update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can take weeks for this or minutes! 
If you sign up to webmaster tools on Google you can change the crawl rate. Ultimately though, Google will decide when to crawl your site and when to make the changes.

Further more, Google does *not* have to display the Meta tags Description attribute on the Google search results page. If Google decides the content on the body of your page is more relevant than the meta tag description, Google will choose that. You cannot control this.

[www.google.com/webmasters/tools/](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)