# Force google not to include my site's name in my pages' title

Tags: seo, google, title

I know this kind of questions has been asked many times, and I know Google changes the title of the page according to the search query and page's content.

I read many articles about this topic, like this :

[**Review your page titles and snippets**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?rd=1)

But my problem is that I think my on-page SEO is pretty good, and my title tag is the exact thing that I want to users see in the Google search result page. But Google adds my site's name in the beginning of the title of results and as I said, I don't want it at all.

As I know, now (Aug 2014), there is no way to tell Google not to change the title of page in the results and show my exact title

Of course I wish there was something like :

`<meta name='areYouSureYourTitleOk' value="Yes,Dont change it,I beg you" />` , but there isn't.

But there must be some way to do this, I mean maybe some changes in my title or meta tags, or even my contents can convince google that my title is the best title possible for the page.

So please help me on this, is there a way or not ?

Answer (score 4):

Google has found that CTR(s) increase with site branding and because Google gauges user satisfaction through CTR, Google sees site branding as a positive thing for it's business. As part of the recent SERP redesign, Google made some changes that includes site branding for shorter title links as an effort to add value. I can understand the heartburn this causes! Unfortunately, the only way to control the title link is to tightly control the title length. Here is an answer that details some of this- ignore the post title:

[Title in Google does not match <title> of document](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65767/title-in-google-does-not-match-title-of-document/65768#65768)

All of this posts points I have experienced and experimented with. I happen to prefer the site branding, however, I originally objected to it. I can understand not wanting site branding and preferring the title to be shown as is. Afterall, you crafted them very carefully for performance. Unfortunately, Google sees fit to make this a moving target. I do not agree that this should happen. Titles should be used as given (in my opinion).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I dont think title length could be effective, look at [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D9%85%D8%B1%DA%A9%D8%B2+%D8%AA%D9%84%D9%81%D9%86+%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%AA+%D8%B4%D8%A8%DA%A9%D9%87+%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D8%B3%D8%B1%DB%8C+U+-+Yeastar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb), You think my title should be longer than that? the '**خانه**'  word at the end, is what google added to my title

Comment: In persian, **خانه** means home, and because of my breadcrumbs ( home > products > ... ), google thinks my site name is '**خانه**' .

Comment: not even Google changes my titles, but also cant recognize my site's name, shame

Comment: Title lengths are measured in pixels these days so I do not know how that translates to your situation. I do not like that Google does this stuff. I take advantage of it very carefully for my site, but would prefer to chose branding and not have it chosen for me. I rather suspect that Google goofed the whole branding thing up for your language. The fact that it is picking up breadcrumbs is very strange. If you have a page you are not as concerned about, you can experiment and use *fetch as Google* as many times as you want (I assume) to see what you get.

Comment: I have a breadcrumb in my language that first item is خانه . but this means home not my brand, i dont know how it discover the company name

Comment: Google does something in the US and then tries to roll it out in other languages and countries- I suspect something very strange is happening though I cannot tell you what that is. I have not seen this scenario before. It is very strange! I prefer that Google would not mess with SERP links, afterall, they are supposed to index the Internet and not just make stuff up. I am confused- I know you are too.

Comment: yeah, you are absolutly right, I think we should create  a campaign to announce Google not change out titles :D

Comment: I agree. Google does strange things from time to time, but they always seem to change their mind after a while, perhaps this is one of those strange things that will simply go away after a while. That is, once Google realizes what a lousy idea it is. Perhaps if we load this question up with keywords- Google, lousy, and idea they might find it? ;-)

Comment: yeah. I hope so :D