# Why is my page title appearing in lower case on Google?

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-search, url

My page title, in google search results is now in lower case, with the exception of our company name. The title tag is in title case:

```html
<title>Free Mobile Home Value - Used Mobile Home Book
Values</title>
```

You can find the page by searching "Free Mobile Home Book Value", The title now reads: "free mobile & manufactured home book value - JCF Lending"

Comment: Based on the title, I am confused abut what I can get  on your website. Do I get a book? What is the value? We should be able to discern this without having to browse the internet for answers.

Comment: Interesting, if you use Duck Duck Go (do people _still_ use google?) it appears as you expect.

Comment: More interest in finding out why it appears in lower case on Google..Just for your info, Mobile Homes have a book value, just like cars..Our site tells them what it is..

Comment: See [Homepage is indexed in Google with a different page title!](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84503/homepage-is-indexed-in-google-with-a-different-page-title).  It doesn't address the lower-case issue, but it says why Google might rewrite your title in general.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the title used in the Google search results looks like it is taken directly from the single `h2` element on the page (there is no `h1`). However, the HTML content is all uppercase - but Google is never going to use an all uppercase title in the search results so would appear to have just lowercased the lot.

> ```
> <h2><span class="style42">
>   FREE MOBILE &amp; MANUFACTURED HOME BOOK
>     VALUE</span></h2>
> ```

Google will often use a different title in the search results from that contained in the `<title>` element if it determines that an alternative title is a better fit for the user's search.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I am going to give changing that a try..